# GPU Shader architecture

Tags: gpu

I have two questions regarding GPU architecture.

Firstly, I was seeing how L1 caches work and noticed that they need to have multiple ports for them to support requests from multiple threads (even after memory coalescing). How many ports do L1 caches have in general? What about L2 caches?

Secondly, in CPUs, the requested block from the cache goes directly into a register file. But how does it work in GPUs? Do they also have multiple ports (equal to the number of ports in L1 cache)? How exactly is it synced with the operand collector?

Is there any document (say from NVIDIA) which explains the detailed architecture of caches, operand collectors and its interaction?

Comment: Is your question "Is there something like L1, L2 Cache in GPU'S"

Comment: No, I know that there are L1, L2 caches in GPUs. I want to know what are the typical number of ports for them (output ports).